# Show that there are exactly 16 pairs of integers $(x,y)$ such that $11x+8y+17=xy$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

**Original problem**

Show that there are exactly 16 pairs of integers $(x,y)$ such that $11x+8y+17=xy$.

**My work**

From case by case analysis I come to know that the equation will hold if and only if $x$ is odd and $y$ is even.

Also I found that $(8-x)|(11x+17)$ and $(11-y)|(8y+17)$

This is all what I have found.

**Please see that my work are right or not.**

This is a new kind of question which I have encountered so please help me is solving this problem.

Comment: All your conclusions are correct and the best way I know is described in my answer ($x$ is odd and $y$ is even is a correct conclusion and $8-x$ divides $11x+17$ and $11-y$ divides$8y+17$ are valid consequences)

Comment: @Elaqqad Sir this was a 10 marks problem of last year paper of an institute entrance exam. I guess that my conclusions only award me 1 or 2 marks. (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261971/show-that-g-is-one-one-if-and-only-if-g-is-onto?noredirect=1#comment2563604_1261971) Please look at this problem. This one of those 10 marks problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $a,b,c$ three integers, the idea when you have an equation of the form:
$$xy=ax+by+c$$
to solve if for unknown integers $x,y$ is to do the following factorization:
$$(x-b)(y-a)=c+ab$$

and hence the number of solutions is the number of divisors of $c+ab$.

Comment: After a search I found (http://www.mathwarehouse.com/answered-questions/factors/what-are-the-factors-of-105-solved.php) please look this. It is showing that the divisors of 105 is 8. Please explain.

Comment: what if you count the negative ones also you will have $16$ divsors and so there are $16$ solutions in total

Comment: I missed that. Thank you Sir. One more help, out of 10 how much you will give for my conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

This type of diophantine equation is solvable by a generalization of completing the square. Namely, completing a *square* [generalizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651073/242) to completing a *product* as follows:

$$\begin{eqnarray} &&axy + bx + cy\, =\, d,\ \ a\ne 0\\
\overset{\times\,a}\iff\, &&\!\! (ax+c)(ay+b)\, =\, ad+bc\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

Here we deduce $\ xy - 11x - 8y = 17 \iff (x-8)(y-11) =\, \ldots$

So by *uniqueness of prime factorizations* the problem reduces to counting the divisors of $\,\ldots$

Comment: Sir can you please look at [my this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261971/show-that-g-is-one-one-if-and-only-if-g-is-onto/1261976?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 0):

16 ordered pairs indeed.

$$\begin{align}
11x+8y+17&=xy \\
xy-11x-8y&=17 \\
xy-11x-8y+\color{red}{88}&=17+\color{red}{88} \\
(x-8)(y-11)&=105=3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7=d_1 \cdot d_2
\end{align}$$

Setting

$$\begin{cases} x-8=d_1\\ y-11=d_2 \end{cases}$$

Implies that
$$\begin{cases} x=8+d_1\\ y=11+d_2 \end{cases} \text{such that} \ \ (d_1,d_2) \in \lbrace \text{divisor-pairs of 105} \rbrace$$
For any divisor-pair $(d_1,d_2)$ that produces one solution, $(d_2,d_1)$ will produce another.

Additionally, for any $(d_1,d_2)$ that produces a solution, $(-d_1,-d_2)$ will produce another as well.

So for every divisor-pair, $(d_1,d_2)$, there will be four total solutions:
$$\begin{align} (d_1,d_2) &\to (d_1,d_2) \\
&\to (d_2,d_1) \\
&\to (-d_1,-d_2) \\
&\to (-d_2,-d_1)
\end{align}$$

This is due to a lack of symmetry in the expressions for $x$ and $y$ ([for comparison, this situation is different](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2404098/419507)).

The problem therefore reduces to finding exactly $4$ divisor-pairs of $105$.
Since $$105=3^{\color{red}{1}} \cdot 5^{\color{red}{1}} \cdot 7^{\color{red}{1}} \implies 105 \ \text{has} \ (1+{\color{red}{1}})(1+{\color{red}{1}})(1+{\color{red}{1}})=8 \ \ \text{divisors},$$

there are indeed four divisor-pairs:
$$(d_1,d_2) \in \bigg{\{} (1,105),(3,35),(5,21),(7,15) \bigg{\}}$$

As an example, setting $d_1=1$ and $d_2=105$

$$\begin{align} (1,105) &\to (1,105) && \implies (x,y)=(9,116)\\
&\to (105,1) && \implies (x,y)=(113,12)\\
&\to (-1,-105) && \implies (x,y)=(7,-94)\\
&\to (-105,-1) && \implies (x,y)=(-97,10)
\end{align}$$

That's four solutions from one divisor-pair alone.