# For how many pairs of positive integers n and m is the statement $mn - 8m + 6n =0$ true?

Tags: geometry, polygons

> Each interior angle of a regular polygon with $n$ sides is $\frac{3}{4}$
>   of each interior angle of a second regular polygon with $m$ sides.
>
> How many pairs of positive integers $n$ and $m$ are there for which this
>   statement is true?

$\frac{(n-2)*180}{n}$ is the value of one interior angle for a polygon with $n$ sides.

Therefore $\frac{(n-2)*180}{n} =\frac{3(m-2)*180}{4m}$ and $mn - 8m + 6n =0$

For how many pairs of positive integers $n$ and $m$ is the statement $mn - 8m + 6n =0$ true?

Comment: Hint: $(m+6)(n-8)=-48$.  There are twenty pairs of integers that multiply to -48.

Comment: Duplicate of [Show that there are exactly 16 pairs of integers $(x,y)$ such that $11x+8y+17=xy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262026/show-that-there-are-exactly-16-pairs-of-integers-x-y-such-that-11x8y17-xy)  (exactly the same methods work here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$mn-8m+6n=0\iff (m+6)(n-8)=-48$$

Comment: So the only pairs I can make with positive integers n and m are $24*(-2)$, $12*(-4)$, $8*(-6)$, $16*(-3)$ and $6*(-8)$. I found the pairs (m,n):$ (18,6), (6,4), (2,2), (10,5)$ and $(0,0)$. Should I include $(0,0)$?

Comment: If you are restricted to positive integer $m,n$, the case $6*(-8)$ drops out...

Comment: Thanks, but why can't I set m=$0$ and n=$0$? Is $0$ not a positive integer?

Comment: You're welcome. No. $0$ is not positive. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_(mathematics)

Answer (score 2):

$$mn-8m+6n=0$$

$$m(n-8)=-6n$$
$$m=\frac {6n}{8-n}$$
The positive integral solutions are $$(m,n)=(2,2),(6,4),(18,6),(42,7),(10,5) $$

Comment: You missed $(42,7)$.

Comment: Thank for the correction

Comment: You missed $(m,n)=(10,5)$.

Comment: Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1):

$$mn-8m+6n=0\implies n(m+6)=8m\implies n=\frac{8m}{m+6}$$
Testing this formula from $1\le m\le 1000$, the only integer solutions found were
$$\frac{2\times8}{2+6}=2
\quad\frac{6\times8}{6+6}=4
\quad\frac{10\times8}{10+6}=5
\quad\frac{18\times8}{18+6}=6
\quad\frac{42\times8}{42+6}=7$$

If we solve the other way around,  $$m=\frac{6n}{8-n}$$ and we can see a limit where $1\le n\le7$ so the pairs are $(2,2), (6,4), (10,5), (18,6), (42,7)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you solve for $m$ in terms of $n$ and impose the condition $m>0,$ you discover that $n<8.$ If you now use the fact that $$\frac{6n}{8-n}$$ is an integer, you should be able to manually list all the solutions.

*Check:* There are five solutions.

Comment: There are $5$ solutions.

Comment: @poetasis Thanks. I'd initially counted five. A misreading made me reduce  it to four.